# IOS/Objective-C: Deallocate web view in Detail View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have a master table and detail view controller.  The detail VC shows URLs through a web view.

If using the built in navigation of the master/detail setup, if I go back and then press a different table cell, the detail view will update the web view.  This is true whether I use a `UIWebView` or a `WKWebView`.

However, within the detail view, without having to go back to the table, I want to give the user the option to view more than one url through the same web view.  I am trying to do this in viewwillappear by changing the url for the request.  However, the `UIWebView` (or alternatively `WKWebView`) continue to show the same url.  I can't seem to get rid of the first url.

I've tried all kinds of ways to close or stop the existing web view, clear the cache, delete cookies etc. before reloading the new one but still see the same url.  Would appreciate any suggestions.  Here is my code and some of the things I've tried that don't work:

```
      -(void) changeURL: (NSNumber*)param {
      NSURL *testurl1=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];
      NSURL *testurl2 =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
      //if param is 1 {
      _urlToLoad = testurl1;}
      else {
      _urlToLoad = testurl2;}
      }
Edit: Method below is updateInterface, not viewWillAppear
     -(void) updateInterface {
        UIWebView *webView;
        NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_urlToLoad];
          webView = nil;//This blocks the web view from loading at all for some reason I can't understand.  Setting wkWebView to nil does not block loading.
        [webView stopLoading];//no effect
        [webView loadRequest:request]; 
        [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:request];
            [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
            NSString *myDomain = @"www.google.com";
            for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {

                if([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:myDomain]) {

                    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
                }
            }
     //wkwebview version
            WKWebView *wkwebView;
            WKWebViewConfiguration *wkConfig = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
            wkwebView = nil;
            wkwebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:wkConfig];
            wkwebView.navigationDelegate = self;
            [wkwebView loadRequest:request];

            [webView addSubview:wkwebView];

            CGRect webFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
            webFrame.origin.y = 100.0; // statusbar
            webFrame.origin.y -= 100.0; // statusbar 20 px cut from y of frame
            webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
           }
```

Comment: This is a bit confusing... If you comment-out **all** of your code in `viewWillAppear`, do you get a "Detail VC" that has a web view and it loads a URL? If so, where is the code that is setting *that* URL?

Comment: Yes I can load a web view fine the first time with [webView loadRequest:request1]; or alternatively  [wkwebView loadRequest:request1].  There is another method not shown that specifies request2.  Once request1 has loaded, I can't get it to load request2.  Stuck on request1;

Comment: I edited question to make this clearer

Comment: Where are you calling `changeURL`?

Comment: in response to a UIGestureRecognizer

Comment: ok - well, it doesn't make much sense to try anything in `viewWillAppear` if the view is already there, and you want to load a new URL into the already visible web view (either kind).

Comment: You're right.  it was actually in another method  in viewwillappear, update interface.  In my mental fog, I was confusing the two.  I am editing the above.

Comment: Ummm.. ok... looking at your edit, you say you call `changeURL` in response to a gesture, but I don't see *that* function calling `updateInterface`?

Answer (score 1):

The `UIViewController` method "viewWillAppear" has the following signature in Objective-C:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

, you implemented it without any arguments.

The result is that, instead of being taken as an override of the original method defined in the superclass `UIViewController`, it is treated as a brand new, custom method introduced by your subclass; and unless you call it explicitly somewhere, it will never execute.

Source: [SDK Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear?language=objc)